# Pyinstaller - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cpuinfo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package this script but I keep getting this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "systeminfo.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cpuinfo'
[6308] Failed to execute script systeminfo
```

I tried this into cmd

```
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import="cpuinfo" systeminfo.py
```

I'm on the latest version of pyinstaller and pip.

This is the import section of my file:

```
import psutil, platform, GPUtil, cpuinfo, os, sys, wmi, winreg, getpass
from tabulate import tabulate
from datetime import datetime
```

When I run it, it just opens up and closes out. But when I run it through CMD, that's when I get that error message.

How do I fix this? I want to include all the modules so I can run this script on different computers that don't have python installed.

EDIT:
I fixed this issue by using this thread: Pyinstaller 'failed to execute' script

I use pycharm so this worked for me.

The only issue is whenever the CMD opens up, nothing happens. The only thing that can printed is if I hardcode a print(). Functions aren't working at all.

Answer (score 0):

fix it with :
pip install py-cpuinfo